# Flex: match if preceded by a character/pattern

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

How to match a pattern `R` only if it is preceded by another pattern `S` without reading `S` (to give `S`-matched input back to *lex*) ?

file.l :

```
%%
\\foo       { 
              yytext++; // To remove the starting backslash
              printf("%s\n", yytext); 
            }
\\          printf("backslash!\n");
.
%%
int main() {
    yylex();
}
```

In the above example i want to accept `foo` only when it is preceded by a backslash `\`.
But in my current implementation i am eating the `\` which is matched below.

To check run as :

```
lex file.l
gcc -lfl lex.yy.c
./a.out
```

---

#### Edit 1:

I tried using unput as suggested by @rici. But as i implemented there are strings having both patterns which do not detect both patterns.

Like `bar\foo`

```
%%
\\foo       { 
              yytext++; // To remove the starting backslash
              printf("foo\n"); 
              unput('\\');
            }
bar\\           printf("bar\n");
.
%%
int main() {
    yylex();
}
```

---

#### Edit 2:

Got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5345273/10721332). It uses flex start condition.

---

#### Edit 3:

```
%x backslash

%%
<backslash>foo      { 
                      printf("foo\n"); 
                      BEGIN(INITIAL);
                    }

bar\\               {
                      BEGIN(backslash);
                      printf("bar\n");
                    } 
.
%%
int main() {
    yylex();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `unput` do what you want?

Comment: @rici Thanks i was not aware of unput. It works for the above case. Though if i change the `\\ ` to something which consumes the backslash before `\\foo` then it would not detect `foo`. One would want to detect both no matter which is scanned first.

Comment: if you could be clearer about what you are really trying to do, it would be a lot easier to provide a sensible answer. Flex is designed to help you split an input into separate tokens. I have the feeling that you might be trying to do something else.

Comment: Actually i wanted to split string constants from the input. For that i had this pattern `[^\\]\"([^\"\n]|"\\\"")*[^\\]?\"`. I was making sure that the starting quote is not delimited (preceded by a backslash). But in doing so i was reading that character and hence i asked this

Comment: If you are using flex to break the input into tokens, there is no need for this check. If a token starts with a quote, the previous character cannot be a backslash because if the previous character were a backslash, the previous token would have included the double-quote, so it wouldn't be at the beginning of a token. Tokenisation is *not* like scanning a string for a regular expression, and it is important to understand the difference. *Every character* in the input is part of some token. That fact makes writing patterns much easier.